# ANOVA comparison different subsets of same data frame

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, anova, linear-model

I am trying to compare two model which are based either on the male or female gender in my data. There is the same number of people in every gender group. Why is the anova function not giving a p-value?

````r
ancova_female_subset <- lm(Y ~ X + covariate1 + covariate2 + covariate3, data = df_female_subset)
ancova_male_subset <- lm(Y ~ X + covariate1 + covariate2 + covariate3, data = df_male_subset)

anova(ancova_female_subset, ancova_male_subset)

Result:

  Res.Df     RSS Df Sum of Sq F Pr(>F)
1     77  968.41                      
2     77 1106.27  0   -137.87         
```
````

Answer (score 2):

It's because they are two different subsets.  When you use anova for model comparison, the models have to be on the same data with different models, usually nested models.

If you want to see if there are significant differences in the models for men and women, you need to look at interactions.  Something like

```
intermodel <- lm(Y ~ sex*X + covariate1 + covariate2 + covariate3)
```

but adding more if you want to look at interactions with the covariates.

If you just want to look at the differences and not test them, then you can compare the models that you already created (one on each subset).